# What is @EnableTransactionManagement XML equivalent in Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring

What is `@EnableTransactionManagement` XML equivalent in Spring 4?

BTW, as a newbie in Spring, I have no idea where to look for such XML equivalents for other annotations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

> I have no idea where to look such XML equivalents for other annotations.

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Comment: Nice, thank you. You gave me an idea for my particular case with hibernate, so +1.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to @LakatosGyula [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36420961/1479414), in case of using `Hibernate` with `Spring` this configuration will do the job:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @Andremoniy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36421061/5349014), following is the updated and complete answer:

- First you need to add the following schema/metadata in your beans
  config file:

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
```

- Then you need to update the `xsi:schemaLocation` tag with below
  schema location:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
```

- Now declare your respective transaction manager using any
  of below:

```
<!-- If using hibernate -->
<bean id="transactionManager" name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

OR

```
<!-- If using JPA --> 
<bean id="transactionManager" name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">   
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

4. Now you need to tell spring about your transaction manager using below:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```