# When Spring commit data to database and Why my exception cannot rollback the transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactional

I am using Spring to manage my transaction by annotation `@Transactional`. However, I found it cannot rollback even though there is a `RuntimeException`.

Firstly, I explain my appliacation structure. This is a web project, deployed in Tomcat. I add already `DispatcherServlet` in my `web.xml`. Then define its configuration in `servlet-context.xml`. In the `servlet-context.xml`, I config the transaction. The database is `mysql-5.7.16-winx64`.

```
<tx:annotation-driven />

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/digitalmenu?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
  <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="root" />    
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
<beans:property name="packagesToScan">
  <beans:list>
    <beans:value>com.shuishou.digitalmenu.account.models</beans:value>
  </beans:list>
</beans:property>
<beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
  <beans:props>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.auto_close_session">true</beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>


    <!-- Enable the second-level cache  -->
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</beans:prop>
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop>
  </beans:props>
</beans:property>
```

For example, I have a service `AccountService`(already annotated by `@Service`). There is a method `addAccount` in this class. I put `@Transactional` in front of `addAccount` method.

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Result addAccount(long userId, String username, String password) {
    UserData user = userDA.getUserByUsername(username);
    if (user != null)
        return new Result("account_existing");

    user = new UserData();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    userDA.saveUser(user);
}
```

Here, `userDA` is a repository which only call hibernate session to save object.

```
@Repository("userDA")
public class UserDataAccessor implements IUserDataAccessor {
    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable saveUser(UserData user) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }
    ......
}
```

This is a simple method. It does not throw any exception so everything run correctly, but if I change a little to let the method happening an error, I found the data is still persisted in database. Here I change the `addAccount` method as below:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public Result addAccount(long userId, String username, String password) {
    UserData user = userDA.getUserByUsername(username);
    if (user != null)
        return new Result("account_existing");

    user = new UserData();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    userDA.saveUser(user);
    int i = 1/0; //-------------------here to create a RuntimeException
}
```

I made a `RuntimeException` at the end of the method. Thoeretically, the user object should not be persisted in database since there is an error. But the data is still entered into database. 
I set a breakpoint at the line of `userDA.saveUser(user);` I found that after java run this line `userDA.saveUser(user);`, the database is alread changed, which is different as I thought. Based on my view, the database should change after the function run finish without any exception.

Therefore, I have 2 questions.

1. Why does my database change before the function code executed finish?
2. Why does not Spring rollback after there is an error/RuntimeException in the function?

Comment: How do you configure your app? through XML or java config?
if the latter you must have @EnableTransactionManagement annotation in it. If you use xml config see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420880/what-is-enabletransactionmanagement-xml-equivalent-in-spring-4
also make sure you import the right Transactional package

Comment: How do you configure your transaction management? How do you obtain the service, and the DAO inside the service, and the sessionFactory inside the DAO? Why do you spedify readOnly = false, since it's the default? Why don't you just use throw new RuntimeException() to throw a runtime exception? Why do you call save(), since the entity is managed, and all the changes made to this entity are thus automatically made persstent by Hibernate?

Comment: How is `addAccount` being called? And what is the configuration of your `LocalSessionFactoryBean` (and do you really need JTA?).

Comment: hi, JB Nizet, I modified my question to answer some of your questions. But for the last question, I really don't know what the difference is between save() and persist(), so I use save() just for try. Meanwhile, in my example, this is a new UserData object, so what's your meaning for "the entity is managed"? I am doubted for the reason why hibernate persist my change automatically. Please give me an explaination. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @M. Deinum, I modified my question just now. Do you mean **LocalSessionFactoryBean** is _<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">_ . About the call of [link](addAccount), it is from the Controller, where the userService class is Autowired.

Comment: @SongtaoLou , before checking configuration , is your database allowing transactions over the calls? Which DB / version are you using? Secondly about the configuration , are you quite sure(logs) that the methods annotated with `@Transactional` are being wrapped over Spring Transaction manager?

Comment: I want to see the configuration (not only the declaration) of the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. And as asked do you really need JTA for transactions? Do you have multiple resources which need to be transactional? If not you don't need JTA.

Comment: @AntJavaDev Thank  you for your good questions. I just know my database version , it is mysql-5.7.16-winx64. But for your other questions, I really dont know. I don't know if MYSQL allows `transactions over the calls`, I also don't know if `@Transactionla` is wrapped over Spring Transaction Manager. Sorry, I am a newbee of Spring, I need more learning about it.

Comment: hmm do you pass any parameters to the jdbc url ? Also check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html). i cant find the default one for the mysql-jdbc-driver, so maybe trying setting this yourself as i can see that your mysql version is supporting transactions without configuring smth. To check whether the methods are being wrapped or not open up the Spring logs in debug.

Comment: Also as @M.Deinum suggested , are you pretty sure that you need JTA , thus BTM

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your warning. I don't know JTA thoroughly. My project's configuration is just copied from one of my company's project. Maybe JTA is needed in that project, but after reading the explaination of JTA, I feel that I don't need it. I only have one database, maybe I need to change totally about my configuration. Thank you.

Comment: @M.Deinum I edit my question and removed the JTA in the configuration xml. But the rollback is still no working.

Comment: You still need a transaction manager, although it now can be a simple one like the `HibernateTransactionManager`.

Comment: HI, guys, I found the reason is that I use MYISAM as my engine. It does not support rollback. After I changed to Innodb, everything is OK now.